# How to identify timefield of the index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there a es query or some way to ask Elasticsearch that which field is being used as time field for a specific index?

Answer (score 1):

When you have index already created and you want to check which field is used as a time field, navigate down to Management/Stack management/Index patterns, select your index and search through the fields. The field that is used as a time field has time (clock) icon next to it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Kibana to choose the right time field (Step 5):**

1. In Kibana, open Management, and then click Index Patterns.
2. If this is your first index pattern, the Create index pattern page opens automatically.   Otherwise, click Create index pattern in the upper left.
3. Enter "your_index_name*" in the Index pattern field.
4. Click Next step
5. In Configure settings, select "@your_timestamp_field" in the Time Filter field name dropdown menu.
6. Click Create index pattern.

Kibana User Guide: [Defining your index patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html)

**Or search in your index mapping for an field with "type: date"**

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping?pretty'
{
  "your_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "your_index" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@**timestamp**" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "@version" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "clock" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "host" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Get Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)

**Or look into your indexed documents:**

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_search?pretty'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "your_index",
        "_type" : "your_index",
        "_id" : "logstash-01.kvm.local",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2018-11-10T18:03:22.822Z",
          "host" : "logstash-01.kvm.local",
          "@version" : "1",
          "clock" : 558753,
          "type" : "your_index"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html)

Comment: Hey Thanks for your thorough answer. Regarding the first section about manual checking through Kibana, I actually need a way to check through code. The latter suggestions through curl, what if there is more than one date field but I am using only one of them for index time field as only one is allowed?